# Usability of toggles as a filter or sorting mechanism

Tags: usability, design-patterns, filter, toggle, sorting

I looked up a website (page link [here](https://theconversation.com/how-do-viruses-mutate-and-jump-species-and-why-are-spillovers-becoming-more-common-134656)) and noticed this at the bottom of the page (one of the few times that I managed to scroll that far):

[image]

It shows a toggle being used to sort the comments added at the bottom of an article, which is something that I haven't seen before (at least used in this scenario).

This is a different pattern to the ones usually used for tables, i.e. dropdowns for filtering or header rows for sorting. I am thinking about the usability of this design pattern and whether it is something that has been specifically created for a mobile first design of a long page.

Any other similar implementation example that anyone has picked up from other types of sites?

Comment: The state of the toggle button oldest/newest in the screenshot results in showing the oldest comments first. Some people might find that logical, but for me it isn't. A good reason to stay away from this kind of toggle buttons.

Comment: I totally agree with @jazZRo here. Sorting comments by default to show the oldest comments first doesn't make sense at all. As a user, I want to see the newest comments first or the most popular comments. That's just a filter converted into a toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to make a simple comment but I don't have the reputation yet ;). Apple is using this type of button ([scope button)](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/scope-buttons/) in some of its app's but its NOT the same way as your screenshot. Apple gave a fine explanation on how to use the scope button:

> Clicking a scope button restricts the scope of content, such as search results, within the view...
>   [More here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/scope-buttons/)

[image: scope button in MacOS]

I (personally) think scope buttons are very nice. They work exceptionally well on mobile (app's). Take a look at this screenshot from the photos app on an Iphone. The Years, Months, Days, All, are all a very clear example on how to use the scope button.

[image: scope buttons on IOS]

Hope it helped you!
Greetings

Comment: +1 the longer answer is welcomed :) Sometimes a short comment isn't enough :D